Power Automate - Birthday Emails using Excel
Running into a block with how Power Automate reads dates in an "MM/dd" format against an Excel file.

From the above sample information, I grabbed the info from the Excel and went for the 'Birthdays'
Birthday value is from Excel, formatted as a Short Date.
utcNow('MM/dd')
"Birthday": {
      "type": "SetVariable",
      "inputs": {
        "name": "Birthday",
        "value": "@item()?['Birthday']"
      }
    },
    "Compose": {
      "type": "Compose",
      "inputs": "@formatDateTime(variables('Birthday'),'MM/dd')",
      "runAfter": {
        "Email": [
          "Succeeded"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Condition": {
      "type": "If",
      "expression": {
        "and": [
          {
            "equals": [
              "@outputs('Compose')",
              "@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM/dd')"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

Trying to get the condition to look to compare the two between each other, but it's throwing an error:


Please do not include references to eternal images, rather include (upload) these images in your question. And have you looked up what ISO8601 format is? It's certainly not 'MM/dd'.

"ISO 8601 represents date and time by starting with the year, followed by the month, the day, the hour, the minutes, seconds and milliseconds."
What I'm pulling, based on the "Apply to each" block is the 1900 date format of the  birthday, when I want to pull the MM/dd/yyyy, and then convert it to MM/dd
"Birthday": "45526" to "Birthday": 8/22/2024

Instead of passing the date from excel directly, convert it to the actual date as Excel's format does not get parsed directly. Format it and then you can use it for further conditions or access.
Here's a sample format
Expression:
addDays('1899-12-30',int(item()?['Date']),'yyyy-MM-dd')

Working:

Output:


Thanks. I'm not sure how the condition would go for this, though. I did use the output and formatted as needed, but it's still not correctly comparing between the utcNow() variable.
